# Angular7: CanLoad Auth guard hangs browser

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-canload

I have created an AuthGuard Service and implemented CanLoad interface to it, as shown below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanLoad, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canLoad() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin')) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Below is my App Routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/guard/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  { path: 'not-found', loadChildren: './not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

No files are being downloaded when I check the browser networks tab and I see a blank white page and 
Below is the warning I see in my browser

```
platform-browser.js:613 Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/882238. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection
```

Comment: This is happening because of routing loop infinitely so check your router navigation

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add  `pathMatch: 'full'` for your path with '', otherwise it would match with every other path as well. Hence you would have an infinite loop, since your AuthGuard would accidentally be called for your 'auth' route as well.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the issue, just needed to reorder by routes as below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  {
    path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { path: 'not-found', loadChildren: './not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have some problem. Guard is only use to check you have permission to access that route or not so it's not ideal to redirect user to different route in the guard.

You must implements CanActivate interface not CanLoad  interface

So your code must change into this

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin')) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: canActivate does download all the files but canLoad doesn't hence it supports lazy loading greatly. Hence canLoad  here checks if user is not logged in then go to login page else download the module.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that default `pathMatch` is set to `'prefix'` and that means every path will match **empty path** on the route which lead to this module. So possible fixes are, setting `pathMatch: 'full'`, like this:

`{
  path: '', 
  loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', 
  pathMatch: 'full', 
  canLoad: [AuthGuard],
},`

or reorder routes as you already figured out [in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55921943/4295768)